# How can I automate refreshing tables in Redshift on a set schedule?

Tags: bash, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm looking for guidance on writing a shell script to reload tables in Redshift on a "morningly" basis. Here's the manual process I'm currently doing and would like to automate:

- Log into the PostgreSQL shell
- Enter my password
- Issue a COPY command (these are different for different tables)
- After it finishes, upload the file to S3 using aws cli
- Open my client (I use Postico), run a truncate command on the table, then run the COPY command to grab the file from S3 and load it
- When its finished, delete the file from S3

Even for two tables, this is a bit much to do every morning. Is it possible to issue these commands from a shell script? If so, can you provide a skeleton or psedocode to do so?

This seems like a happy medium between a cron job and paying money for a "glue" product like Stitch.

Comment: It would be a good idea to edit your question and post some things you've tried yourself. Most people are not going to write your script for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guidelines on [How to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This website is not a place to ask for guidance, but rather to get specific programming help. You should show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Yes, that is very much possible. You need not even have to pass the connection parameters and/or credentials - everything can be done through a script.